# React Hook to find user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to use the React useState Hook for an online project. What I want to happen is, when I type the users name in the search box, It will find the users card on the browser. I am able to log the user to the console, but I am stuck on how to get it to render on screen. Tried so many ways and just not getting it.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCYBG.png)

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import {robots} from './robots';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';


function App() {

  let [searchInput] = useState('');

  function onSearchChange(e) {

    searchInput = e.target.value;

    const filteredRobots = robots.filter(function(robot){
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
    });

    console.log(filteredRobots);

  }



  return (
    <div className='tc'>
      <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange} />
      <CardList id={robots.id} name={robots.name} email={robots.email}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CardList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import {robots} from './robots';

function CardList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      robots.map(function(user) {
        return <Card key={user.id} id={user.id} name={user.name} email={user.email} />
      })
    };
  </div> )
}

export default CardList;
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'tachyons';


function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className='bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow shadow-5'>
      <img src={`https://robohash.org/${props.id}`} alt="Robot" />
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <p>{props.email}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.js file, the searchInput is not being set to the state

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import {robots} from './robots';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';


function App() {

  let [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

  function onSearchChange(e) {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value)   

  }
    **You can pass the filterRobots in place of robots to get only words passed in the search box**


 const filteredRobots = robots.filter(function(robot){
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
    });



  return (
    <div className='tc'>
      <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange} />
      <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the CardList File

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';


 function CardList({robots}) {
  {
    robots.map((user, i) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={i}
          id={user[i].id}
          name={user[i].name}
          email={user[i].email}
          />
      );
    })
  }
}

export default CardList;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked. The only thing I have a question about is why do we use ```id={robots[i].id} instead of  id={user[i].id}``` ??

Comment: Sorry about that, I intended to use robots. Will edit.Thanks will edit

Answer (score 2):

React only re-render when you set a state to a new value.

Check the code below:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import {robots} from './robots';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';


function App() {

  let [searchInput, setSeachInput] = useState('');

  function onSearchChange(e) {
    
    // set state here to re-render
    setSeachInput(e.target.value);
  }

  // use might want to use useMemo to improve this, I just want to make it simple now
   const filteredRobots = robots.filter(function(robot){
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
    });

    console.log(filteredRobots);


  return (
    <div className='tc'>
      <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange} />
      {/* using filteredRobots herer*/}
      <CardList id={filteredRobots.id} name={filteredRobots.name} email={filteredRobots.email}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: My bad. `email` props of `CardList` need to use  `filteredRobots` too

Answer (score 1):

You should not be mutating the `searchInput` value like `searchInput = e.target.value`. It is better to call a setter function to update the value. For example,

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

// to update the value of searchInput call setSearchInput
function onSearchChange(e) {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value)
}
```

State changes are asynchronous. When you try to filter the `robots` it is not guaranteed that it will be called with the latest value of `searchInput` that's why you should be using `useEffect` hook which will filter the robots when the value of `searchInput` changes.

Here is a solution,

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import {robots} from './robots';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';


function App() {

  let [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  let [filterdRobots, setFilteredRobots] = useState(robots);

  function onSearchChange(e) {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     setFilteredRobots(robots.filter(r =>
       r.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())))
  }, [searchInput, robots])



  return (
    <div className='tc'>
      <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange} />
      <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

check the [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-gglpi?file=/App.js) for demo

Comment: I am not familiar with the useEffect Hook. I've only been using react for a couple weeks. Your answered worked but a little too much o grasp right now lol

Comment: It's alright, stay positive and you will learn it for sure.  Here are some nice resources to learn how `useEffect` works.[react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), [another article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)